# Hotreload Gulp не работает

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-watch

Подскажите, пожалуйста, не работает автоматическое обновление стилей на странице. Работает только при сохранении sass файла:(

```
var gulp      = require('gulp'), 
sass        = require('gulp-sass'), 
browserSync = require('browser-sync'); 

gulp.task('sass', function(){ 
    return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.sass')
        .pipe(sass()) 
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css')) 
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true})) 
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() { 
    browserSync({ 
        server: { 
            baseDir: 'app' 
        },
        notify: false 
    });
});
gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync', 'sass'], function() {
    gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.sass', ['sass']); 
});
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 0):

[gulp-livereload](https://github.com/vohof/gulp-livereload#livereloadchangedpath) подойдёт?

```
gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync', 'sass'], function() {
    livereload.listen();

    gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.sass', function(file){
       livereload.changed(file)
    });
});
```

Можно ещё [Browsersync](https://browsersync.io/) попробовать.